# is there any easy way to get fancybox 2 to animate left to right instead of up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a project i'm working on and using fancybox 2 (which is pretty great).

That said, one annoyance is that the arrows in a gallery point left and right, but the animation moves up and down. i'd really love to animate the new content in from the left, rather than the top.

Before i pull apart the default rollout of fancybox and start overwriting oncompletes and the such, is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest source code - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master
Includes different animation directions depending on the way you navigate (using scroll mouse or keyboard navigation keys).

You can get horizontal transitions using the `left` and `right` key arrows.

No need to hack or customize your own fancybox version.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's how i did it, if anyone else runs into this question later.

example: [The Fremont](http://www.ziba.com/thefremont)

in the plugins.js file, i've made my own version of the fancybox script. changeIn and changeOut are updated as so:

```
   if(!isForward){
      // move left (backwards)
      startPos.left = (parseInt(startPos.left, 10) + 1500) + 'px';
      wrap.css(startPos).show().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '-=1500px'
            }, {
                duration: current.nextSpeed,
                complete: F._afterZoomIn
            });
        } else {

    // move right (forwards)
    startPos.left = (parseInt(startPos.left, 10) - 1500) + 'px';
    wrap.css(startPos).show().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '+=1500px'

            }, {
                duration: current.nextSpeed,
                complete: F._afterZoomIn
        });
    }
```

and changeOut looks like this now:

```
    changeOut: function () {
        var wrap = F.wrap,
            current = F.current,
            cleanUp = function () {
                $(this).trigger('onReset').remove();
            };

        wrap.removeClass('fancybox-opened');

        var leftAmt;

        if(isForward){
            leftAmt = '+=1500px';
        } else {
            leftAmt = '-=1500px';
        }

        if (current.prevEffect === 'elastic') {
            wrap.animate({
                'opacity': 0,
                left: leftAmt
            }, {
                duration: current.prevSpeed,
                complete: cleanUp
            });

        }
```

isForward is defined in the next/prev function

```
     next: function () {
      if (F.current) {
         F.jumpto(F.current.index + 1);
         isForward = true;
           }
      },

      prev: function () {
      if (F.current) {
         F.jumpto(F.current.index - 1);
         isForward = false;
           }
      },
```

and that's that. enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Good idea. Just, there is a bug in you code. you must put

```
isForward = false; or isForward = true;
```

before

```
F.jumpto(F.current.index - 1); or F.jumpto(F.current.index + 1);
```

in both next and prev function. Since it break your code when you press next and then you press prev. you can try it.

```
next: function () {
        if (F.current) {
            isForward = true;
            F.jumpto(F.current.index + 1);
        }
    },



prev: function () {
            if (F.current) {
                isForward = false;
                F.jumpto(F.current.index - 1);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API, maybe there's an option for it?

If not, find the part of the code that does the animation and replace it with your own.

Comment: ...which is what i did. i'll post the results in a bit, but i added some code to the "changeIn" and "changeOut" functions, and also tracked which direction you were heading. works like a charm. probably should be in the std build (i'll submit to github)